# Handlebars are slipping and the stem is cutting into my bars. How do I fix this? New bars and stem or just a new stem?

Tags: repair

I bought a 2014 kink curb and I think I may need to buy new bars because my stem is cutting into them. I don't know though. If anyone could please help me with this.

Comment: Please use English.

Comment: You've got to put a little more effort (and punctuation) into your question if you want some help. Maybe a picture to show what you're talking about.

Comment: If the handlebars are slipping in the stem clamp, the clamp is not tight enough.  If there is no remaining gap between the two sides of the clamp where the screw tightens it, you need to 1) replace the clamp, 2) replace the handlebar, or 3) insert a shim (can be cut from a beer can) between clamp and bar.

Comment: Take it back to the retailer! If the bars of your 2014 bike are moving in the stem you have a serious assembly error.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on design, try ensuring all bolts are tightened evenly (so if the top two are done up all the way and the bottom two are not, undo them all and redo them evenly)